# Ubuntu 23.04 programs show "X not responding" before system freezes up completely

Tags: crash, 23.04

Around a month ago I installed Ubuntu 23.04 switching from Manjaro. I formatted the entire disk and set up home directory encryption. I'm dualbooting with Windows 10.

Sometimes, after about an hour or maybe more of using my desktop, I will randomly receive a "X not responding" prompt over whatever application I'm using. This happens to Firefox, Steam, Signal, and so on. Nothing happens when I click close and it shortly spreads to every other open application before completely freezing my system.

I don't know what logs to gather in regards to this. I've never experienced something like it and I don't know what to pin this issue down to, especially since it started happening the very week I installed Ubuntu.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

log of `free;uptime`:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        15140672     6136452     1100116      365676     8594540     9004220
Swap:        4194300           0     4194300
 13:27:52 up 13:43,  2 users,  load average: 0.74, 1.07, 1.17
```

Comment: Are you running out of free memory? That behaviour sounds like it could be a consequence of thrashing

Comment: How much RAM, swap? Do: `free;uptime`. Read `man free mkswap swapon fstab filefrag`. Without swap, when memory (RAM) fills up, the kernel runs a pseudo task, the "OOMkiller". It "picks" a task, and killd it to free up some memory. Lather, rinse, repeat until "enough" memory is free. Sometimes the killed killed tasks aren't critical. Swap is good, if you have swap as big as RAM, you can hibernate. Swap must be contiguous. Do not use `dd`, it will create a fragmented file.

Comment: I have 16gb RAM and 4GB swap, which has been enough for my arch gnome desktop in the past. I'm gonna update the main question with the result of `free;uptime`. I didn't suspect OOM because this is a laptop and I don't tend to use it for very intensive stuff. I'll look around more.